# Images on top of a category

Tags: prestashop

i am trying to set up a new menu for my prestashop website but i am new on this platform and i'm not a web developer, i want to add images as category thumbnail. Like this website menu https://www.imballaggi-2000.com/

i have already tried to look into other forums but i didn't found anything
i tried to search for some youtube videos but they doesn't meet my requirements
is there anybody that have already done this things?.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is next. 
You need to modify your menu template file. Go to `store_root_path/themes/your_theme/modules/ps_mainmenu/ps_mainmenu.tpl` and add this in the beginning of a link

```
{if $depth == 0 && $node.image_urls}
    <img src="{$node.image_urls[0]}" alt="{$node.label}" />
{/if}
```

before condition `{if $node.children|count}`. This is it.
Then in your admin panel just assign **Menu thumbnails** images to all categories you need. Be aware that you can add more than one image but the first one will be displayed. Also, I presume that images should be displayed only on the first level if I am wrong just remove `$depth` variable from the condition.
P.S. I described the approach for Prestashop 1.7* if you use Prestashop 1.6 the method may not work.